# Exact binomial test. Directional hypotheses - how to explain differences in results?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution

Let's assume the following problem:

> A sample of 30 subjects has been drawn from a specific population.
>   It has been proved that the expected rate of some negative events among the subjects in similar populations is about 10%.
>   I want to check if the rate of the events in the population: a) exceeds 10%  b) doesn't exceed 10%  (by using directional hypotheses) if there are specific number of events reports (see the example below):

- 1 event out of 30 subjects, H1: p<0.1

  ```
  binom.test(1, 30, p=0.1, alternative="less")

  Exact binomial test

  data:  1 and 30
  number of successes = 1, number of trials = 30, p-value = 0.1837
  alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is less than 0.1
  95 percent confidence interval:
   0.0000000 0.1485961
  sample estimates:
  probability of success 
              0.03333333
  ```

The upper bound of the confidence interval is p~0.15 and this is greater than 0.1. That's OK, we cannot reject the H0 saying that: "The true rate is equal to or exceeds 0.1"

OK, let's try to check how many events must happen to reject the opposite hypothesis:

- 7 event out of 30 subjects, H1: p>0.

  ```
  binom.test(7, 30, p=0.1, alternative="greater")

  Exact binomial test

  data:  7 and 30
  number of successes = 7, number of trials = 30, p-value = 0.02583
  alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is greater than 0.1
  95 percent confidence interval:
   0.1149869 1.0000000
  sample estimates:
  probability of success 
               0.2333333
  ```

OK! So 7 was enough, yet 6 - not:

```
        Exact binomial test
data:  6 and 30
number of successes = 6, number of trials = 30, p-value = 0.07319
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is greater than 0.1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.09087406 1.00000000
sample estimates:
probability of success 
                   0.2
```

Well, I don't understand. Why for a SINGLE event and H0: p>=0.1: the confidence interval reached 0.15 and for SEVEN events and H0: p<=0.1 it starts from about 0.11?

So 1 event is to small to say "less than 10%" and minimum 7 events is required to say "greater than 10%"?

How to explain it logically?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the distribution is asymmetric around the proportion you stated.

Comment: This answer is a bit sparse at the moment. I think it would be clearer if you could expand on it somewhat.

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot understand this explanation. How the "asymmetry" causes different results in the given example? Please help me more!